# boost converter control technique

Tags: control, boost, converter

Is it possible to design a high power wide input supply range boost converter which has to be compatible with single phase as well as three phase power supply? and if it is possible then which analog control technique is suitable for it?

Answer (score 1):

Without more info I'd say yes- A three phase rectifier followed by a filter cap and a boost stage (boost PFC maybe) could work on a single phase input or three phase.  You could get high power out with an interleaved boost or even a single phase boost, but without defining exactly what you need it's impossible to say more. Probably peak current mode control with slope compensation would be the way to go.

Assuming you are talking about a non-isolated boost.  If you go to an isolated topology there are a lot more possibilities.  Phase shifted full-bridge would be good for high power.

Comment: Sir, I am talking about non-isolated boost converter topology. my input power is near to 20kw and minimum input supply voltage is 200V ac. My problem with rectifier + filter stage is that peak amplitude of current drawn from the supply is very high and filter capacitor value is also near to 7mF.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to design a high power wide input supply range boost
>   converter

Yes, but regulations require it to be power factor corrected.

> which has to be compatible with single phase as well as three phase
>   power supply?

You can't use a traditional 3 phase rectifier because power factor correction circuits won't work correctly. You would design three individual PFC circuits that fed a common DC bus hence, it would naturally be compatible with 1, 2 or 3 phase supplies: -

[image]

The [picture source](https://www.eetimes.com/document.asp?doc_id=1272370) explains that a traditional 3 ph rectifier approach is not viable.

Comment: While it's true that many countries require PFC, and if you want to sell a product world-wide YOU probably want PFC too, there are countries like the US that do not require PFC (yet, anyway).  Since the OP only asked "is it possible" I didn't rule out the 3-phase rectifier approach.  But you're correct that if you do need PFC it doesn't work...

Comment: @Andy aka Sir, I am not getting your approach. when I connect 3 phase supply then total power will divide into three converters but when I connect single phase supply then whole power will flow through only one pfc converter, so if I want to design a converter of 10kw then according to your approach I need to design three individual pfc converter of 10kw.

Comment: It all boils down to whether you are required to have power factor correction in your country. Regulations in most countries will insist that anything over a few tens of watts do have it. This means you have to approach the 3 phase design as I have shown i.e. a 3 ph rectifier cannot be used. Then, if you want 10 kW from 3 ph each "block" supplies 3.3 kW. If you want 10 kW from a single phase then the inputs get paralleled.

Comment: I don't need PFC, my requirement is that the boost converter should work on single phase as well as three phase rectified input supply. I am thinking to implement peak current mode control using uc3842, I am concerned about feedback loop for such wide input range(1-phase 220V ac to 3-phase 500V ac rms) converter and when single phase rectified ac is applied to boost converter I am not sure that boost converter will work because the input supply will approach to zero in every half cycle.

Comment: I think I’ve answered your question to at least my satisfaction. Sure, timely comments and timely upvotes will be warmly responded to but I made my last comment over a month ago. I’m done with this question and stand by my answer.

Comment: First of all sorry for delay sir, just help me with selection of topology. Shall I go with Peak current mode control or average current mode control? The solution of using three pfc converters will be very costly and will take more space in the machine, I need to make is cost effective and small in size. please guide.

Comment: I can only tell you what is legally acceptable in my neck of the woods. I might also suggest that you take note of the driving force behind the motivation of folk answering questions and that is upvotes (when an answer is useful to you or other folk) AND "question acceptance" by the asker when the question is fully answered and is the best of the bunch.

Comment: [Take the 20 second stack exchange mini tour to understand](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour) what I'm talking about.